# Is it possible to edit a photo caption after it has been uploaded to facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Is it possible to edit a photo or a video caption and description **after** it was uploaded to facebook using the GraphAPI?
what I mean is can you upload the video using your own application and some time afterwards the application updates the caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the Graph API, just HTTP POST to the `{photoId}` with the updated parameters in the form post.  Play with that functionality here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me

Comment: Haven't had the chance to test it yet. I will in the next couple of days. I am testing it on a video and I hope it will act the same.

Comment: It does not work. I tried to change the parameter 'name' of a photo and got the error '(#221) Photo not visible'. (I just uploaded that photo with the same access token)

Comment: I get the same error, and I am requesting access user_photos,publish_actions,publish_stream

Comment: It could be that the photo is not visible to the API just yet.  It takes time for propagation to happen.  It's happened to me even with adding comments to a newly added post.  In January I did try using the API Explorer tool and it worked fine.  But, it's been nearly 3 months and who knows what all has changed in the API since then.  If it is no longer working, then log a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and report back here with the bug link so others can see it.  Thanks.